# 'Cannot find name system' in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a routes file in which system exits but in my vsc it shoews error cannot find name 'system'.Here i attached the screen shot.[image]

Answer (score 5):

This occurs because Typescript doesn't know the `System` object.

Install the `SystemJS` typings

```
npm install @types/systemjs --save-dev
```

Add a reference to the typings in your `tsconfig.json`, under `types`

**tsconfig.json**

```
"typeRoots": ["node_modules"]
"types": ["system"]
```

Of course if you intend to run this code in the browser, you must also have the `SystemJS` script linked in your app for `System.import()` to do anything:

**index.html**

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

**Sidenote:**

To get max performance out of your app, you may eventually want to use lazy-loading (to load only those modules the user needs). The way you're loading other modules (dynamic loading with `System.import()`) may not be compatible with lazy loading:  [Here is the recommended way](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#lazy-load)

Consider replacing:

```
path: 'inbox', loadChildren: ()=> System.import('../inbox/inbox.module')
```

With:

```
path: 'inbox', loadChildren: 'absolute/path/to/inbox/inbox.module#InboxModule'
```

Comment: BeetleJuice,the type error still remains and i added in this way     "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "node",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
      
    ]
   
  },
   "typeRoots": ["node_modules"],
      "types": ["system"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],

Comment: @nlr_p You have two `types` entries.  Move `system` to the first entry

Comment: Use `SystemJS` not `System` as the global name, the latter is deprecated at the top level scope.

Comment: Same problem using Angular 7. The correct file to patch is not tsconfig.json, it is tsconfig.app.json